# Synchronizing data between two organizations

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-2013

I'd like to create a shadow copy of my main organization to play around in without risking damaging the data. The schema is easy to move over using solutions but what about the data?

Moving the data using export/import functions would kill a lot of time. I'd like a utility that does that for me, so I can move out data daily or at the very least weekly.

Suggestion on method? Do I need to go to third party products? Or do I have to code one myself?

Comment: Have you considered SQL Server backup of production DB and restore on test server?

Comment: Yes, I have. However, I only have a single server and the secondary organization is on the same one as the production. The only difference is that you need to add */Playground* in the URL (that's the same of the lab organization). So, what I'd need is **strictly** a tool for copying all the records between *Org1* and *Org2* on the same server and relying on the same solutions. Backups will be managed in a totally different environment that I've got no access to. (I **hope** the the backups will be managed, at least.)

Comment: You can try restore production database under different name (i.e. Playground_MSCRM) and import it as _Playground_ organization. Obviously you'll have to delete current playground org. I don't believe there will be any other easy way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Instance Adapter for CRM allows for you to keep two organizations in sync.

You will also need the Connector for Microsoft Dynamics, it is available on partner or customer source.  The connector is a tool that allows you to integrate and sync the different Dynamics products like CRM, GP, or NAV.  With the instance adapter for CRM you should be able to setup an integration between 2 CRM orgs.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35385

If you are using CRM 2013 you should read this blog post as support has been dropped after a certain version of the connector.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dynamicsconnector/archive/2013/10/17/microsoft-dynamics-crm-2013-is-supported-by-connector-for-microsoft-dynamics.aspx